# Dual view with Nvidia GTX 770

Tags: nvidia, screen

I have a PC with 2 Monitors (connected via displayport to a nvidia gtx770 and the other one to the asus z87-pro c2 mainboard)

When I installed Ubuntu 13.10 everything was exactly as i wanted it to be. Both monitors working and the right one extending the left. Both had 2560x1440px.

The only problem I had was the fact, that it seemed that Chromium didn't use hardware acceleration and it told me to install different drivers for my cards to make it work.
Also the mouse flickered sometimes (only while hovering special applications - i.e: chromium, sublime text)

So I thought: Maybe I can get more performance out of this if installed the Nvidia drivers. That's exactly what I did. I added the edgers ppa and installed nvidia-current.
When I ended up with a blackscreen there I tried bumblebee, ... and everything else (of course I always purged everything before trying something else), optimus, but didn't manage to get my system working.

The only thing that seemed to work a bit, was when connecting both monitors to the nvidia card (one displayport and the other one hdmi) but then I only got a 1080p resultion of one of them.

I already googled a lot and I read this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/378655/fail-to-setup-dual-monitor-in-ubuntu-13-10-with-nvidia-gtx-780

But how is it possible that Ubuntu manages to do this out of the box and with Nvidia drivers there is no way.

I'd really like to get this to work and not just waste the performance I could have for nothing.
Or is there a way to just use better drivers the ubuntu way and use hardware acceleration in chromium. (without just skipping chromiums warnings - as people suggest for this kind of thing, but recommend not to do it)

thanks in advance guys :)

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question on http://ubuntuforum.org and got the answer. The answer was my HDMI cable was limiting my resolution on the second monitor, not the performance of my graphics card.

So I tried it with a dvi cable for the second monitor and connected it both cables to the nvidia card and tada ... everything works great with the nvidia119 driver now.

I get full resolution, no more flickering, no more crashes (so far).